# How do discrete logarithm with modulo a prime and a non-prime compare?

Tags: cryptanalysis, discrete-logarithm, attack

Let
$c_N = g^i \mod N$ and $N=p \cdot q$
and
$c_P = f^j \mod P$ and $P$ a prime

We assume $N,P$ has the same bit-length. $P$ is the best type of prime you can choose (e.g. safe prime). $N$ is a product of two or more primes. Those factors are also chosen as best as possible. $g,f$ generators for largest group possible.

Now an attacker given $c_N,c_P, P,N,g,f$ want to derive $i$ or $j$.

1. Which would be the faster way to go?
   As far as I know for the non-prime case he needs to factorize $N$ first.
   In case the prime would be the faster way, how about the following:
2. How would it change if the attacker also know $\varphi(N)$
3. ...and all factors of $\varphi(N)$
4. Would it be equal if $\varphi(N) = \varphi(P) =P-1$ (or very close to, ignore condition same bit-length here)
5. We assume $N$ is a product of more than 2 factors. And the attacker only know the two largest factors of $\varphi(N)$, (or largest 3)

Comment: It seems to me that cases 1, 2, and 3 are quite similar since given $\varphi(N)$ you can factorize $N$.

Comment: In a discrete logarithm setting you are asking for the logarithm, i.e., $i$ and $j$ in your example while the group element $m$ which is usually a generator of the (sub-)group is publicly known. Also, if $j$ was known, one could just compute $m$ as we can easily compute $\varphi(P)$. If we do not know $m$ and $j$ then there exists a $j$ for every $m$ and so $m$ is information theoretically hidden.

Comment: For the non-prime case everything depends on the subgroup $m$ lies in.... essentially then the same reasoning as for the prime case applies...

Comment: @mephisto thanks for the hint, change $m$ to known generator

Comment: @MarcIlunga in 1. $\varphi(N)$ is unknown. For 2. only if two factors in $N$ or $varphi(N)$ or? true for 3.

Comment: If you knew the largest three factors of $\varphi(N)$, you have a good chance at deducing $\varphi(N)$ (and hence factor $N$)

Comment: If you know the factorization(or infer it) you can solve for each factor independently and combine. solving two problems of half the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first establish some things. As we assume that f, g are generators of the biggest possible subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/P\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ respectively, we know that $f = P-1$ and $g = q-1$ for $q$ the largest factor (assuming for simplicity this is no prime power). In the following I assume that $P$ and $q$ are of the same "quality", i.e., they both are such that $P-1$ (resp. $q-1$) has at least one large prime factor, etc..
Hence, if $P = q-1$ and q is known, then the two cases are essentially the same (you can map one to the other). This should answer 4. and 5. 8assuming that this was what 4. was aiming for). As in cases 3.) and 2.) $q$ can be easily computed or is known, it depends on the size of $P$ and $q$ which case is harder. The one in the larger group is harder. 
Remains the 1st case. I would guess that if $P$ and $q$ are of the same size, there is still no difference. Most generic attacks do not need to exactly know the group order. However, you might want to check if the index calculus algorithm (and variants thereof) require knowledge of the order of $g$ or if they also work when only $N = pq$ is known.

Comment: So that means if N and P have the same bit-length the non-prime is the faster way (case 1.). (if chosen all a factors as best as possible)

Comment: Yes, would say so.